# Редирект подкаталога .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

Мне нужна переадресация вида:

`catalog/[тут любой текст]/filter/clear/apply/` на  `catalog/`

Код который у меня есть:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/catalog/$ /about/ [R=301,L]
```

Проблема в том, что я не могу вписать после каталога поддиректорию.

В `/about/` отправляю ради теста.

Как написать RewriteRule и каким регулярным выражением выбрать любой текст в данном случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/.*/filter/clear/apply/$  /catalog [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Выглядит логично но все же не сработало. Если поменять регулярное выражение .* на статику все равно остается на тойже странице, я думаю это связано с тем что используется больше одного слеша в пути.

Comment: @Jaikrexe вы имеете ввиду еще слэши между `catalog/` и `/filter/.....`? Нет, они не влияют. Вот прямо сейчас протестировал у себя запрос вида `/catalog/74747/444/333/filter/clear/apply/` - переадресовывает на `/catalog`. Неработоспособность может быть связана например с тем, что есть правила RewriteRule стоящие перед этим и портящие "картину".

Comment: Да вы правы, поставил в начале файла и заработало, спасибо огромное!

Comment: @Jaikrexe Пожалуйста. Но имейте ввиду, что теперь это правило может навредить нижестоящим. Но если повезет - то все будет гут!